# A differentiable function whose Fourier series is not uniformly convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

We focus on $2\pi$-periodic functions.

1- Does there exist any differentiable function whose Fourier series is not uniformly convergent?

Even more,

2- Does there exist any differentiable function whose Fourier series con not be uniformly convergent on every set of positive measure in [$-2\pi,2\pi$]?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you already know the two things I have to say about this:  (i)  Dini's test shows that if $f$ is differentiable then the Fourier series fo $f$ converges *pointwise* to  $f$ (ii) it follows, and it's also easy to prove directly, that if $f$ is continuously differentiable then the Fourier series converges to $f$ uniformly. (Because $f'$ continuous implies $\sum n^2|c_n|^2<\infty$, hence $\sum|c_n|<\infty$.)

But if $f$ is just differentiable does that imply the Fourier series for $f$ converges uniformly? I haven't concocted an example, but surely not; if $f'$ exists but is not continuous then the differentiation is not uniform.

Comment: By definition $f'$ is continuous.

Comment: @ManUtdBloke What??????????????????